# How to do a low RAM full cross join?

Tags: mysql, unix, memory, awk, cross-product

I have a hope to perform a full self-cross join on a large data file of points. However, I cannot use programming language to perform the operation because I cannot store it in memory. I would like to find all combinations of points within the set. Below would be an example of my dataset.

```
x y 
1 9 
2 8 
3 7 
4 6 
5 5
```

I would like to cross join on this data to generate 25-row table containing all the combination of points. Would there be a low memory solution? perhaps with `awk` ?

Thank you,

Nicholas Hayden

P.S. I am a novice programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps in two steps, create a header, column1 and column2 files and join the column1 and column2 and append to header file

```
awk 'NR==1{print > "cross"} NR>1 {print $1 > "col1"; print $2 > "col2"}' file
join -j9 col1 col2 -o1.1,2.1 >> cross
rm col1, col2
```

obviously make sure the temp and final file names won't clash with the existing ones.

Note, the `join` command on MacOS doesn't have the `-j` option, so change it to equivalent long form

```
join -19 -29 col1 col2 -o1.1,2.1 >> cross
```

in both alternatives we're asking join to use the non-existent 9th field as the key which matches every line of the first file to every line in the second to generate the cross product of the two files.

Comment: Apologies if this is an unintelligent question. I am receiving a `usage` error with your `join -j9 col1 col2 -o1.1,2.1 >> cross` command

Comment: what is the full error message?  what OS, which shell?

Comment: `usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field] [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2` I am running `bash` on mac os.

Comment: OK, your version doesn't have `-j` option, change to `-19 -29`

Comment: Thank you! It works! What do options `-19 -29` mean?

Comment: Why would using `join` use less memory than reading the data into any other tool?

Answer (score 1):

If the memory usage wasn't an issue I'd probably do this:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { print; next }          # print the header
      { x[NR]=$1; y[NR]=$2 }          # read data ro two hashes x and y
      END { for(i=2;i<=NR;i++)
                for(j=2;j<=NR;j++)
                    print x[i],y[j]   # print all combinations of x and y
      }' file
```

Keeping the memory usage low obviously requires keeping data out of memory and that means accessing the file a lot. So while processing `FILENAME` for `x`, open the same file with another name (`file` below) and process that record by record for `y`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { print; next }          # print header
      { file=FILENAME; x=$1; nr=1     # duplicate FILENAME, keep $1, create local nr
        while((getline <file) > 0)    # process file record by record
            if(nr++>1) {print x,$2 }  # print $1 of FILENAME and $2 of file
        close(file) }' file           # close the file
x y 
1 9
1 8
1 7
1 6
1 5
2 9
...
```

I'd probably never use that code as it is for anything useful but maybe you can mix those 2 solutions to create something suitable.